# Adding 1,15,30 or 45 minutes to currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, datetime, time

does anyone know how to add minutes to currentTimeMillis. i am passing an integer t, which is how many minutes users would like to add to the currentTimeMillis() time_int. Is this possible in java? can anyone show me?

```
  public void radioStartTime(int t)
    {
    time_int =(int)System.currentTimeMillis(); //casting long into int. 
    System.out.println(time_int);
    }
```

Comment: Do you just want to calculate the time x minutes from now, or do you actually want to update the system time?

Comment: Have you considered using `TimeUnit`, which has been brought to life to avoid exactly such confusion you are now in?

Comment: Why are you casting a long to an int to start with? That will lose data. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, given that there are 1,000 milliseconds in a second and 60 seconds in a minute, you need to add 60,000 for each minute.

Hence:

```
Add n minutes, n =               Add
       1                      60,000
      15                     900,000
      30                   1,800,000
      45                   2,700,000
```

I'd also be a little wary of converting the return value from `currentTimeMillis()` back to an `int` data type, you may want to keep it as a `long` so there's less chance of losing range.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't possibly work. An `int` can only hold up to `(2^31)-1`. If you use it to hold milliseconds, that's only about 24 days from January 1, 1970 -- so you *can't* hold the current time. You either need to use a `long`, or divide by 1,000 and store the time in seconds.

Comment: i am no longer casting to int.